# How to get the current time?

Tags: datetime, sml, smlnj

I looked at the [TIME signature](http://sml-family.org/Basis/time.html) for Standard ML and tried the following:

```
- Time.now;
val it = fn : unit -> Time.time
```

So it gives me back a function - how do I get the current time in Standard ML?

Comment: Why the downvote with no comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't give you back a function, it is a function.
Try some other functions and the output is very similar:

```
- List.hd;
val it = fn : 'a list -> 'a
- String.str;
val it = fn : char -> string
```

`Time.now` is a function from `unit` to `Time.time`.
The only value of the type `unit` is written `()` (which is also called "unit"), so you call it like this:

```
- Time.now ();
val it = TIME {usec=1516525299967615} : Time.time
```

Comment: So the big takeaway is that a unit is a type to represent a value that has no meaning? I tried writing a function with zero arguments & it was a syntax error - so this makes sense - a unit is used to invoke a no-argument function?

Comment: @Winny All ML functions take one argument (and produce one value). I suppose you can consider `()` a value that contains no information, which is as close to nothing as you can get in ML.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function which returns the current time. I.e., do `Time.now ()`.